# Take data from a div and write it to text file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to take data from my div an add it to php file:
my javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#save').on('submit',function(e) {
        var bufferId = document.getElementById('data2save');
        $.ajax({
            url:'saver.php',
            data:{id : bufferId},
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                alert("ok"); //=== Show Success Message==
            },
            error:function(data){
                alert("not ok"); //===Show Error Message====
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //=== To Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"===
    });
});
```

my html part is:

```
<input type="button" value="save" id="save">
<div id="data2save">
    Data to be added.
</div>
```

and my saver.php file is:

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['id'];
if (($fp = fopen("test.txt", "w"))){
    fwrite($fp,$data);
    fclose($fp);
    echo "ok";
}
?>
```

Can someone please point out the issue?

Comment: Why do you think there is an issue? Does your code do anything different than you expect? What is it?

Comment: where is info1 element in HTML? what error you are getting?

Comment: sorry that is data2save instead of info1. It is actually not making the file.

Comment: In your code, `bufferId` is a **DOM element**. jQuery doesn't know how to convert a DOM element to a string. And please [edit] your question to correct it and add the necessary information.

Comment: @JaveriaHabib is my solution not working?

Comment: @CezarisLT nope. It is still not working.

Comment: @FelixKling Then how can I get the data from div?

Comment: The way CezarisLT posted is correct. However, you have to bind the submit event handler to the **form**, not to the `input` element. The submit event is not triggered on the button. I recommend to [learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging). Add some `console.log` statements and see what exactly is executed and which values the variables have.

Comment: @FelixKling I got it. I changed button to div and used click instead of submit and now it is working. Thanks :)

Comment: @CezarisLT your correction is working now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have a wrong selector, replace `document.getElementById('info1');` with `var bufferId = $("#data2save").html();`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#save').on('submit',function(e) {
        var bufferId = $("#data2save").html();
        $.ajax({
            url:'saver.php',
            data:{id : bufferId},
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                alert("ok"); //=== Show Success Message==
            },
            error:function(data){
                alert("not ok"); //===Show Error Message====
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //=== To Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"===
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As **document.getElementById('data2save')** is an DOM element. You cannot sent it directly as data in the AJAX request.

Replace it with **document.getElementById('data2save').value** and then let us know if it works.

The new javascript would be like this

```
(document).ready(function(){
    $('#save').on('submit',function(e) {
        var bufferId = document.getElementById('data2save').value;
        $.ajax({
            url:'saver.php',
            data:{id : bufferId},
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                alert("ok"); //=== Show Success Message==
            },
            error:function(data){
                alert("not ok"); //===Show Error Message====
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //=== To Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"===
    });
});
```